# plots.jl heatmap does not preserve orientation

Tags: julia, julia-plots

I'm trying to use the heatmap function fro plots.jl as a simple means to visualize small grayscale pixel grids.  But I've discovered that this function does not preserve the orientation of the matrix it plots.  For example:

```
julia> using Random, Plots

julia> mymatrix = zeros(Int, (5,5))
10x10 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0

julia> mymatrix[1,1] = 1
1

julia> mymatrix
5x5 Matrix{Int64}
 1  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0

julia> heatmap(mymatrix, color = :greys)
```

Which results in the following image:

[image: heatmap of binary matrix]

You can see that the heatmap function transforms the provided matrix.  From the examples I have tested, it is clear that a vertical reflection is applied.  I cannot find anything in the documentation about this behavior.  I am looking for a way to avoid or corrected it, ideally without changing the input matrix.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `yflip` keyword argument:

```
heatmap(mymatrix, color=:greys, yflip=true)
```